# sending message from client to server and vice versa

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have the following code for client and server

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <inttypes.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <strings.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 int socket_fd;
 struct sockaddr_in  dest;
 struct hostent *hostptr;
  struct { char head; u_long body; char tail; } msgbuf;

 socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 bzero((char *) &dest, sizeof(dest)); /* They say you must do this */
hostptr = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
dest.sin_family = (short) AF_INET;
bcopy(hostptr->h_addr, (char *)&dest.sin_addr,hostptr->h_length);
dest.sin_port = htons((u_short)0x3333);

msgbuf.head = '<';
msgbuf.body = htonl(getpid()); /* IMPORTANT! */
msgbuf.tail = '>';

 sendto(socket_fd,&msgbuf,sizeof(msgbuf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest,
              sizeof(dest));

return 0;
}
```

server:

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <inttypes.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <netdb.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <strings.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    int socket_fd, cc, fsize;
    struct sockaddr_in  s_in, from;
    struct { char head; u_long  body; char tail;} msg;

   socket_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

   bzero((char *) &s_in, sizeof(s_in));  /* They say you must do this    */

 s_in.sin_family = (short)AF_INET;
 s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    /* WILDCARD */
 s_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)0x3333);

  printsin( &s_in, "RECV_UDP", "Local socket is:");
 fflush(stdout);

bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof(s_in));

for(;;) {
fsize = sizeof(from);
cc = recvfrom(socket_fd,&msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fsize);
//printsin( &from, "recv_udp: ", "Packet from:");
printf("Got data ::%c%ld%c\n",msg.head,(long) ntohl(msg.body),msg.tail); 
fflush(stdout);
}

return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to change this code so that:
1.The client will send my name to the server and then will receive the server response. 
2.On the server side, the server will receive the client name (instead of the current msg structure) and will send back its name.

**I'm assuming I should just put my name in the msgbuf.body like this**

```
     msgbuf.head = '<';
     msgbuf.body = 'liana'; 
     msgbuf.tail = '>';
```

and delete the 
     msgbuf.body = htonl(getpid()); line.

or maybe make a new string for my name like this string name="liana";
and put it in the msgbuf.body like this msgbuf.body=name;(???)

**is this the right deriction?**

for reciving the response of the server I assume it is the same way as it was done for the server
**should I add to client something like this?**

```
int socket_fd, cc, fsize; // the socket that we receive to
 struct sockaddr_in  s_in, from; // decleration of the server and sending 
 (to the server) struct
  fflush(stdout);//to ensure that whatever you just wrote to a file/the console is indeed written out on disk/the console.

  bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_in, sizeof(s_in));// conecting 
  between 
 the socket and all the details we entered

  for(;;) {//infinite loop
fsize = sizeof(from);//set the size of the socket we resive to
cc = recvfrom(socket_fd,&msg,sizeof(msg),0,(struct sockaddr 
 *)&from,&fsize);//recive massage using UDP protocol
printf("Got data ::%c%ld%c\n",msg.head,(long) ntohl(msg.body),msg.tail); 
//print the whole massage
fflush(stdout);//to ensure that whatever you just wrote to a file/the 
console is indeed written out on disk/the console.
```

}

**and just leave it like this without changing anything?**

**how can I make the server receive the my name (instead of the current msg 
   structure)and send it back?
   should I send it back using the

```
sendto(socket_fd,&msgbuf,sizeof(msgbuf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest,
          sizeof(dest));
```

line?
**if I cant use the structure anymore how should i change this line?****

any help whould be appreciated,I'm kind of new to C and never worked with the client/server model

Comment: Remember that in C `'x'` and `"x"` are two different things. Always use double quotes for strings.

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  Do not randomly indent the code

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to ensure the desired command line parameters were actually entered by the user.  If the desired command line parameters were not entered, then output to `stderr`, a USAGE statement telling the user what is expected in the way of command line parameters

Comment: when defining a `struct`, always include a `tagname` as that is what most debuggers use to be able to access/display the individual fields of the struct

Comment: a call to: `fflush( stdout );` is not needed if the preceeding format string ends with `'\n'`

Comment: what is this: `printsin( &s_in, "RECV_UDP", "Local socket is:");`?

Comment: the variable `from` is being declared as in `int` but the call to `recvfrom()` is expecting the parameter to be declared as: `socklen_t`

Comment: the server, probably, should be using a sequence like:  `sock_t sock = socket(...) ... listen( sock, anumber );  newsock = accept( ... )`

Comment: the C library functions always indicate if the function was successful (or not)  when not successful, call `perror(...)` to output your error message and the text of why the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`.